# The completion of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

I would like to ask if, assuming that any metric space can be isometrically embedded in a complete metric space, there is an easy way to prove that the completion of $(\Bbb Q, |\cdotp|)$ (where $|\cdotp|$ is the euclidean metric) is $(\Bbb R, |\cdotp|)$.

I know that the standard way of doing it is to show **directly** that the completion satisfies the ordered field's and linear continuum's properties by means of which $\Bbb R$ can be defined axiomatically. However I am curious to find out if we can **cut corners** and use some other result to more easily prove that the completion has such properties.

---

As always any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: What definition of $\Bbb{R}$ are you working with?

Comment: @peek-a-boo You are right to ask that. I would say a set that has the properties I have quoted above (ordered field, linear continuum).

Comment: Would you consider proving there is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ cutting corners? Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in rings with identity we can find a morphism $\varphi$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and this morphism is characterized by the image of $0$ and $1$, which are just $0$ and $1$ in the reals, and they generate the ring. By existence of inverses we now have the rest of the rationals so $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.